# Binary and ordinal scale

Tags: logistic, ordered-logit

I know my response variable is ordinal(5 levels). I decide to ignore all the information in the response variable and group it into two groups. I then fit a logistic regression model to it. I use this logistic regression model for classification for the two groups.

Alternatively, I fit an ordinal logistic regression model, with this ordinal logistic regression model I use it for classification for my outcome but only for classifying objects in the predefined groups that I choose before fitting the binary logistic regression model.

Which model will perform better when assessed with the $AUC$?.

Comment: More information is always better. Your ordinal logit should work better than binary. Why are you asking this question? Is there something else to this?

Comment: I think the ordinal regression model uses more parameters, in small data sets, it will be a problem estimating these parameters. And the binary regression on the other uses less parameters and less information. What is the trade off between these alternatives?. That is my main concern. I try to formulate  it as a Bayesian problem. First the binary model correspond to model with no prior. The ordinal model correspond to a binary regression but with prior information for other categories.

Comment: You say that in small data sets more parameters will be a problem. But hemorrhaging statistical power, which is what you get by aggregating, also an issue in small data sets?

Comment: I don't think there is a clear answer to this because everything hinges upon how the binary classification threshold was determined and the information loss that resulted. If there is great information loss, the AUC will be lower. Otherwise, the AUC will be either the same or higher. Unless you have good reason to collapse ordinal into a binary, it's a bad idea to do it.

Comment: @rocinante. I work with this oncologist who has just two treatment to administer. He want to determine which treatment lead to bad toxicity. But toxicity is measure in mild, moderate and severe. The issue is at the end of the day they will only do two things. Is it a nice think to predict 3 classes and collapse into 2 or collapse these classes before prediction?

Comment: @ChamberlainFoncha The best thing to do is not to do any classification at all. Toxicity is a continuous variable (measured in percentage or absolute terms). From your description, I don't see why it's necessary at all to collapse this into 3 categories, let alone 2.

Comment: The toxicity is late toxicity (2 years), the oncologist only assess serial photos of the irradiated part. The grading then is in 3 levels. So it is not a continuous outcome. But the assumption of a latent outcome might be appropriate.

Comment: @ChamberlainFoncha 1/2 If the original data already comes classified at 3 levels (i.e. you don't know the original values), then you should do the analysis with those 3 levels. To re-categorize it into 2 is risky because you have the problem of calculating the appropriate cut-off. Unless there are no/few observations in one category, it does not make much sense to collapse from 3 to 2.

Comment: 2/2 If you only want 2 in the final analysis, perform the prediction using the 3 classes and then collapse the results into 2 classes. That way, how you determine the cut-off will not have impact upon the calculation; it will only have impact on the interpretation of the results.